# Using tikzpicture or pgfplots to draw a uniform grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to use `pgfplots` or `tikzpicture` to draw a uniform grid as illustrated in below. The grid size in the figure is `8×8`. I want to be able to define a parameter that gives me the ability to draw grids with different sizes, for example, `16×16` or `32×32`. Could someone help me how I should do it?

[image]

Comment: What is the specific reason to use `pgfplots`? It seems to me that a `tikz` solution would do the job just fine. But I don't know your final/complete use case.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant I wanted to use a `tikzpicture` in my `LaTeX` document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `tikz`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\newcommand{\Grid}[2]{%
  \def\maxX{#1}
  \def\maxY{#2}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) rectangle (\maxX,\maxY);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,\maxX}{
    \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,\maxY);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\maxX*0.5,0) -- (\maxX*0.5,\maxY);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (\maxX*0.25,0) -- (\maxX*0.25,\maxY);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (\maxX*0.75,0) -- (\maxX*0.75,\maxY);
    }
    %
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,\maxY}{
    \draw (0,\y) -- (\maxX,\y);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (0,\maxY*0.5) -- (\maxX,\maxY*0.5);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0,\maxY*0.25) -- (\maxX,\maxY*0.25);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0,\maxY*0.75) -- (\maxX,\maxY*0.75);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
  \Grid{8}{8}

  \Grid{4}{4}

  \Grid{16}{16}

  \Grid{32}{32}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using `grid`...

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1mm]{standalone}

\newcommand\mygrid[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black,line width=1pt] (0,0) grid[step=1] (#1,#1);
    \draw[red,line width=1pt]   (0,0) grid[step=2] (#1,#1);
    \draw[black,line width=4pt] (0,0) grid[step=4] (#1,#1);
    \draw[black,line width=4pt] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
  \mygrid{4}
  \mygrid{8}
  \mygrid{16}
  \mygrid{32}
\end{document}
```